# when ip conflict, how tcp react?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

When two computers are set the same ip address in a LAN(such as 192.168.1.100), both of them may receive  incomplete packets. How does tcp on them react to this situation ? Will they ask for retransmission ?

Comment: I'd suggest you set up a couple [VMs](https://www.virtualbox.org/), open [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), and try it!

Comment: This may depend on your network and how the routing of packets is set up (e.g. [layer 2 vs layer 3 switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAN_switching)). On a layer 3 switch, there may be no problem, since it would cache based on the IP.

Comment: I'd expect it to depend mostly on the race condition of the ARP replies. ("I have .100!", "No, I have .100!") Since the devices have the *same* IP, that means they're in the *same* subnet - so Layer 3 routing has nothing to do with this. It's all about **who** is in the ARP cache (for the source, if he's in the same subnet, or for the router if he's not).

Comment: It's an incorrect situation so the correct behaviour is undefined. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two situations that can occur from this, one of the computers will be able to communicate fine while the other cannot at all, or they both will not communicate (if it stored the MAC ADDRESS in the ARP cache it will still try to route to the first computer on the network).  Also, depending on the direction, if a computer that does not have a duplicate address trying to contact one of the duplicates, it will not the correct computer because they will be fighting over who has the ip address.  If you swap that scenario, it will be asking for re-transmissions but no guarantee that it will ever get them, which leads back to them fighting over the response of who do I send it back to.

Comment: Now how about some rationale for what you think will happen.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that TCP will reset the connections because of sequence number errors.  So, connections will mysteriously and randomly disconnect, depending on when the stack detects the sequence number error.